# Display specific page (that is child) content on parent page

Tags: wp-query, loop, pages, the-content

I have problem displaying child page content on parent page (both static). 
I can display other page content but only if on same level. It dosent work in relation parent - child.

```
<?php
    $investor_content_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'pagename'    => 'current',
        'post_parent' => 'investor-relations'
    ) );
    if ( $investor_content_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $investor_content_query->have_posts() ) {
            $investor_content_query->the_post();
            the_content();
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found solution. What I really needed was parent page slug in "pagename"  argument.

```
'pagename'=> 'investor-relations/current'
```

*And working solution:*

```
<?php
    $investor_content_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'pagename'=> 'investor-relations/current'
    ) );
    if ( $investor_content_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $investor_content_query->have_posts() )
        {
            $investor_content_query->the_post();
            the_content();
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were being too specific/not passing the correct parameters into your `wp_query`.
This should get you what you're looking for:

```
<?php
$current_page_id = get_the_id();
$investor_content_query = new WP_Query( 'post_parent'=> $current_page_id ) );
if ( $investor_content_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $investor_content_query->have_posts() ) {
        $investor_content_query->the_post();
        the_content();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: tried this but doesn't work.